# Gerber viewer confusion - missing traces

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers, gerber

I'm not sure about my gerber files. I guess there is something wrong.

In different gerber viewers the PCB looks right. But in online viewers from JLCPCB and PCBway, the bottom view looks wrong. Some traces are missing.

Bottom layer (everything is there):

[image: bottom layer]

Bottom view (some traces are missing):

[image: bottom view]

Where are the missing traces? It's only a 2 layer board. And all traces are displayed in the bottom copper layer, but not in the bottom view. The top layer looks fine. I don't understand this.

Comment: It may help or be relevant to know what software you created the board in.

Comment: It's made in Eagle

Comment: Not an Eagle user, but did you get any error messages or warnings? The sliver of copper beside the vertical plane split looks suspiciously outside of limits (too narrow).